# Form Validation only work once on one page, will not work on other pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, formvalidation.io

How to fix the issue where the form, and form validation will only load on one page and only once, and will not work on the other page at all. I want reuse that same form which exist on `index.html` but I want to place it to `product.html`, and when I do that, the form validation will not load, even though I just copied the code from `index.html`. Is that default behaviour of the **Form Validation**? I am also using the "old" Form Validation since I have to use that, with JQuery and everything.

This is the code I have:

```
<form id="product-search" name="product-search" data-show-messages="true">
/*...*/
</form>
```

Now when I load this form on index.html it does work, but if I for example load that same Form Validation **twice** on index.html it does not work, only the first one that is placed works.

### working version

```
<form id="product-search" name="product-search" data-show-messages="true" novalidate="novalidate" class="fv-form fv-form-bootstrap">
/* ... */
</form>
```

This happens when everything loads properly

Comment: Where is your form validation JS logic? That's the code we need to see

Comment: maybe you are giving both of them the same id?